# How to place a Required field validator programmatically in a certain place

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a field validator that is created programmatically, how can i place it in a specific place in my aspx page?, right now it justs puts it next to the field but i want it somewhere else, how can i do this?

Comment: Add it to the container you'd like to see it at... `Container.Controls.Add(MyNewValidator);`

Comment: Some code would help immensely, so we can see how you're adding the validator to the form.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't know if I fully understand your question, but you should be able to add the validator to any container you want.

```
<asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server" ... />
<asp:PlaceHolder ID="PlaceHolder1" runat="server" ... />
```

Code-behind:

```
RequiredFieldValidator val = new RequiredFieldValidator();

//populate validator properties

PlaceHolder1.Controls.Add(val);
```

Answer (score 0):

If the location is fixed, use the ASP.Net Placeholder control to place the validator.